# Navigation property is not saved when using independent association approach on EF 4.1

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

Following is a save routine on existing record. What's wrong with this? I'm using [independent association](http://www.ladislavmrnka.com/2011/05/foreign-key-vs-independent-associations-in-ef-4/)

There's no error emitted, however, the Country_CountryId field on Person table didn't change, everything else are properly persisted. What's wrong on the following code/approach?

```
public JsonResult SaveUpdate(Person p)
{
    p.Country = new Country { CountryId = new Guid("EF0CD98E-7138-4757-866E-ADC3C8D216DA") };

    using (var db = new TheDbContext())
    {
        db.Entry(p).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;                
        db.SaveChanges();       
    }

}
```

Here's my mapper:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

    modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().HasRequired(x => x.Country)
        .WithMany(x => x.Persons)
        .Map(x => x.MapKey("Country_CountryId"));

    modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().Property(x => x.RowVersion).IsRowVersion();


    modelBuilder.Entity<Country>().HasKey(x => x.CountryId);

}
```

Here's my models:

```
public class Country
{
    public virtual Guid CountryId { get; set; }

    public virtual string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public virtual string CountryName { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}


public class Person
{
    public virtual Guid PersonId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Username { get; set; }

    public virtual string Firstname { get; set; }
    public virtual string Lastname { get; set; }
    public virtual byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }


    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead and it will work:

```
public JsonResult SaveUpdate(Person p)
{
    var country = new Country { CountryId = new Guid("EF0CD98E-7138-4757-866E-ADC3C8D216DA") };

    using (var db = new TheDbContext())
    {
        db.People.Attach(p);
        db.Countries.Attach(country);
        db.Entry(p).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;                
        p.Country = country;
        db.SaveChanges();       
    }
}
```

Independent associations require special care because each association itself has its own state which must be configured.

Comment: Thanks, that works. Do I need to attach both entities? The code is ok even I just attached the Country entity only

Comment: You don't have to. This is just more descriptive without hidden behaviors.